# Only able to edit source of a schema/component in SDL Tridion

Tags: schema, tridion

I am designing a schema with embedded multimedia schema (images, etc). When I  saved it and open again with CME, the design view is gone and I can only go to source view to change it.

[image: NoDesignViewForSchema]

Even worse, you are presented with a source view only as well when you are trying to create component based on the schema. To me, this is seriously usability issues. Writing xml without tool support is terrible. 
[image: NoDeisgnViewCreateComponent]

I am not sure anyone has similar experiences, any solutions?

Comment: Somehow your schema is interpreted as a so-called complex schema. Normally this should only happen when you change something in the source XSD of the schema that Tridion recognizes as something it **can't** build a form for. Can you add the source of your schema to the question?

Comment: Please post the source of your schema and also what you want to achieve with the schema design.  There is probably a way to do it using the standard scena design instead of a complex design.  We might also be able to suggest using a GUI extension or other 'twist' to achieve your desired results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tridion supports two types of schemas:

1. Web Schemas
2. Complex Schemas

Tridion provides a web interface for building web schemas and can generate an input form for the editors to then enter content into Components based on those schemas.

For complex schemas Tridion simply provides a text area for editing the source of either the XSD or the actual XML content of the component. The rationale behind this is that customers will use some external XML editor (such as XML Spy) to handle these content types.

The distinction between the two schema types is made automatically by Tridion as you edit a schema. When it finds something that it can't generate a form for, it switches to "complex schema mode", hiding the friendly form-builder controls.

Normally you should only be able to turn a regular web schema complex by manually editing the XSD on the source tab in the web interface. You may of course have found another way to accomplish it, in which case I'd love to hear how you accomplished it.

And definitely share your XSD source with us, since that'll allow us to help you convert the schema back into a Web Schema.

Comment: I understand the situation right now. I don't think I manually edited the schema. Anyway, it is not so important. What I am saying is that this situation can be (and should be) improved.

Comment: If you are sure you didn't manually edit the Schema, then maybe the embedded schema is causing it (which might then be the one that is manually edited). If all you want was to notify you don't like the product behavior, you should enter an idea at http://ideas.sdltridion.com

Comment: Thanks, Bart! That should explain it. It must be the embedded schema is being manually edited.